# Cannot locate an element using appium in ios

Tags: java, selenium, appium, wait

I am not able to locate an element despite the fact that using appium inspector the element is located using the same locator I use in code.

```
                By by = By.xpath("//UIATextView[@value='hey!!!!!']");
                boolean result;
                do{
                    device.swipeUp();
                     result = waitUntil(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));
                }while (!result);
```

Where my waitUntil is defined as :

```
public boolean waitUntil(ExpectedCondition<WebElement> condition){ 
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(device.getDriverWrapper().getIosDriver(),5); 
  wait.withTimeout(1,TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
  try { 
    wait.until(condition); // i wait until the condition will be met (with a time out of 1 seconds) and return true 
    return true; 
  } 
  catch (Exception e) { 
    return false; // if after the timeout of 1 seconds has reached then i retrun false 
  } 
}
```

I see that the device keeps swiping up although the element is presented.
Any idea?

Comment: could you please share the definition of `waitUntil` in your code? B'coz at least this is for sure that this method is always returning `false` in your case.

Comment: public boolean waitUntil(ExpectedCondition<WebElement> condition){
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(device.getDriverWrapper().getIosDriver(),5);
        wait.withTimeout(1,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        try {
            wait.until(condition); // i wait until the condition will be met (with a time out of 1 seconds) and return true
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false; // if after the timeout of 1 seconds has reached then i retrun false
        }
    }

Comment: Share the `swipeUp()` method implementation as well please. Also please don't catch `Exception`, unless there is some thing you are totally in control of and you want to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking forward to wait until an element is located on the screen, you can use something similar to the following snippet :

```
By by = By.xpath("//UIATextView[@value='hey!!!!!']"); //any locator strategy
new WebDriverWait(driver, timeToWaitInSeconds)
                .until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {
                    public WebElement apply(WebDriver d) {
                        return driver.findElement(by);
                    }
                });
```

OR something simpler like this shall also resolve things :

```
By by = By.xpath("//UIATextView[@value='hey!!!!!']");
result = driver.findElement(by);
boolean result;
while (!result){
   device.swipeUp();
   result = driver.findElement(by);
}
```

Comment: not working. the driver keeps swiping up and never stops when the element is located

Comment: if you are sure that the element is located, then `result` shall be set true. I believe something is missing here while debugging.

Comment: this is the thing. when i use the same xpath using the appium inspector the element found and i can click on it. i know that result should be set to true but its not. i am not sure what is happening